# Convert map to mapPartitions in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a code to analyze the log file using `map transformatio`n. Then the `RDD` got converted to `DF`.

```
val logData = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/syslog.txt")

val logDataDF = logData.map(rec => (rec.split(" ")(0), rec.split(" ")(2), rec.split(" ")(5))).toDF("month", "date", "process")
```

I would like to know whether I can use `mapPartitions` in this case instead of `map`.

Comment: why do you need map partitions for?

Comment: The simple answer if you absolutely need to use mapPartitions is to convert back to RDD. However, DataFrames should be used instead of RDDs because the [RDD-based API is likely to be removed in Spark 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api).

Comment: Actually there is no need. I would like to know whether there is a way to rewrite this code with mapPartitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your use case but you can definitely use `mapPartition` instead of `map`. Below code will return the same `logDataDF`.

```
val logDataDF = logData.mapPartitions(x => {
  val lst = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, String, String)]()
  while (x.hasNext) {
    val rec = x.next().split(" ")
    lst += ((rec(0), rec(2), rec(5)))
  }
  lst.iterator
}).toDF("month", "date", "process")
```